# Create new dataset by reformatting existing dataset

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe (df) with 10 columns. I am interested in making a new dataframe, one column (col2) is sorted according to values of another column (col4). To use a more simple example, my dataframe currently looks like:

```
col1  col2    col3    col4
32      12     40      1
36      23     20      1
23      10     19      3
12      13     52      2
40      31     18      2
```

However, I am only interested in col2 values as sorted by col4 values. I would like my new dataframe to look like this, so I can easily work with the data in each new column.

```
col4 values    1       2      3    
col2 values    12      13     10     
               23      31
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You want to reshape specific columns to wide. After installing and loading `tidyverse` the next code can help you to reach the expected output:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- mydf %>% select(c(col2,col4)) %>%
  group_by(col4) %>%
  mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=col4,values_from=col2,
              names_sort = T) %>%
  select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
    `1`   `2`   `3`
  <int> <int> <int>
1    12    13    10
2    23    31    NA
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
mydf <- structure(list(col1 = c(32L, 36L, 23L, 12L, 40L), col2 = c(12L, 
23L, 10L, 13L, 31L), col3 = c(40L, 20L, 19L, 52L, 18L), col4 = c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```